# How to check angularfire authentication status in app.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am following the angularfire tutorial to authenticate users. 
Users are able to register, signin and even signout in the app.

When I try to use a resolve to check for $requireSignIn() for some routes(ui-route), it doesn't work.

Also, I want to do a check for user authentication status($onAuthStateChanged()) in my app.js where my modules are loaded. Then if there is a change in authentication, update authentication service( userAuth). I am using ng-show="authData" / ng-hide="authData to change html for logged in elements. But sometimes even after login, some of these elements are still showing as not logged in. I think this has something to do with the authentication update status.

If a user is logged in and the try to visit the login/signup page send them back to home page.

Here is my app.js

```
angular
  .module('myApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngResource',
    'ui.router',
    'ngMeta',
    'firebase'
  ])

   .run(["$rootScope", "$state", function($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
      if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {

        $state.go("home");
      }

    });
    }])

  .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',
   function( $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, ngMetaProvider, $location, userAuth) {


    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');


    $stateProvider
        .state('/', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            meta: {
              'title': 'Goaf | Your next great destination',
              'description': 'This is the description shown in Google search results'
            }
        })
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl',
        meta: {
          'title': 'Goaf | Your next great destination',
          'description': 'This is the description shown in Google search results'
        },
        resolve: {

        "currentAuth": ["userAuth", function(userAuth) {
          return userAuth.$requireSignIn();
        }]
      }

    })


  }]);
```

Here is the controller for the home page where I want only logged in users:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('HomeCtrl', ["currentAuth", function ($rootScope, $scope, $http, $interval, $location, userAuth, dataservice, currentAuth) {

    $scope.authData = userAuth.isLoggedIn();

  }]);
```

And here is my userAuth service file:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('userAuth', ["$firebaseAuth", function($firebaseAuth) {
    var firebaseAuthObject  = $firebaseAuth();

    this.login = function(loginEmail, loginPassword){

       return firebaseAuthObject.$signInWithEmailAndPassword(loginEmail, loginPassword);
    };

    this.isLoggedIn = function(){
         return firebaseAuthObject.$getAuth();
    };

    this.signOutUser = function() {
      firebaseAuthObject.$signOut();

      console.log('logging out user!');
    };

  }
 ]);
```